SQL Server setting a default format when displaying columns
In SSMS or Visual studio writing:

query: select 1.234567 -> display: 1.234567
query: select format(1.234567, 'n') -> display: 1.23

For a long query it is heavy:
select format(1.234567, 'n'), format(1.234567, 'n'),
       format(1.234567, 'n'), format(1.234567, 'n')

Is there a way of setting a default display format for floats or at least at query level?
I did not find any solution. I am expecting a setting in SQL Server or SSMS or VS or at query level.

There is no such setting, no. Alternatives include creating a view or computed column, or using a different data type in the first place (e.g. a decimal with the right precision). You should also avoid format() and use convert() instead, as the CLR overhead of format() is significant.

Why do you care about the display in SSMS or VS? They are just dev tools. Surely you only care about display in your app?

@DaleK i'm guessing the data is copypasted to some excel :)

@siggemannen I bet you're right, and if that's the case, then formatting the Excel column would be best!
